# Loop to run a series of queries to append a table for each record in a different table. MS Access 2010

Tags: for-loop, ms-access, foreach, vba, ms-access-2010

Here is what I need to do:

I have a series of queries that I use to create a final report with multiple columns of statistics for an item.  I have a table set up with a key for each item. What I need to do is create a loop that runs the series of queries for an item and uses the final query to append the results to "report" table.

I have all of the Make Table queries set up and the final Append query. There are two queries that require the key, the rest of the queries are dependant on the results of the first two. So, I need to use that key as a parameter in those two queries. What I need is a loop that will for each key in the "Items" table run the queries on that key, then loop.

I have a module setup to run the complete set of queries, but right now I need to run it for each item. My thinking is that I need a "for i in items..." type loop, but I do not know how to do that in VBA

Using MS Access 2010

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you want to run multiple queries where queries are saved in a table. Some of the queries depends on parent query.

pseudo logic:

1. Run and Execute Parent Query
2. If result exists retrieve value
3. Start loop until parent query has values

   1. Retrieve/construct sub queries
   2. Execute sub query
4. End loop

some pseudo code:

```
dim MyDb as Dao.Database
dim myRs as Dao.Recordset

set mydb = currentdb

dim SQL_PARENT as string
sql_parent = "" ' Retrieve your parent query here
sql_parent = vba.replace(sql_parent, "searchkey", "replace_key") ' Replace keys
' or if you have the keys in a table then use the dlookup() function to replace keys

set myrs = mydb.openRecordSet(sql_parent)
'do error trapping here

dim iResult = nz(myrs("ResultField"),"")
'follow the parent query operation

'construct the sub queries
dim RS_SUB as DAo.Recordset
dim SQL_SUB as string

dim I as integer
for i = 1 to total of your query collection
   sql_sub = query_collection(i)
   sql_sub = vba.replace(sql_sub,"searchkey",iResult)
   set rs_sub = mydb.openrecordset(sql_sub)

next i
```

**note:** this is just a pseudo answer to help you to understand the possibilities to your scenario.